# Eclipse/MinGW/CDT/GDB and problems with debugging

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I have some C++ code and try to debug it.
main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    graph<int> a;
    a.add(1);
    a.addEdge(1,2);
    std::vector<int> answ = a.getAdjacent(1);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < answ.size(); i++)
    std::cout<<answ[i]<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have a breakpoint on "graph a;". But when I start debugging, I get:

```
The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)
No source file named C:\Users\home\workspace\graphcpp\main.cpp.
[New Thread 3552.0xdc8]
```

What's the problem?

Comment: This code seems not complete (where does the `graph` template type come from?), but since the error seems not related to the contents of the file, all the graph stuff is distracting; I think a minimal code would be "`int main() { /*line-break*/ return 0; /*line-break*/ }`" and put a breakpoint on line "`return 0;`".

Comment: @gx_ Same problem with `int main() { /*line-break*/ return 0; /*line-break*/ }`

Comment: Simplify your PATH as much as possible (temporarily). I've seen eclipse having issues with valid path it did not like. Is this a makefile project? Try refering to paths in msys way (/c/users/home...).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems to be a relatively frequent reoccurring issue when using eclipse +cdt with gdb. Changing the default launcher from *GDB (DSF) Create Process* to *Standard Create Process* seems to solve the issue most of the time.

You can find this option under *Preferences->Run/Debug->Launching->Default Launchers*:

[image: Default Launchers]

Also make sure you are compiling with `-g` debug info enabled.

Comment: I don't have a Standard Create Process; just the first displayed option, and Legacy Create Process.

Comment: standard was renamed to legacy. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=426586

Comment: Thanks that solved the issue for me, but I wander why Dsf does not function correctly

Comment: I have a project from `Makefile with existing code` and I have the same problem, but I can't find this menu option? Is it in the `Makefile` this setup or am I missing something?

Comment: @Elod Which version are you using and do you mean you cannot find 'Preferences'

Comment: I'm using  `Eclipse Version: 3.8.1` and the `Run/Debug Settings` has no drop-down option (only one window, with my launch configurations). The debugging stops at a line: `if (this->nextState != NULL) 
  delete this->nextState;`. No error massage and if I execute `if` step, than application stops: **The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)**  `<terminated, exit value: 0>gdb`

Comment: @Elod Perhaps give Luna SR2 release a try -- it comes packaged with CDT 8.6.0. I just checked it out and the setup is the same except its renamed to `Legacy Create Process` as tzafrir pointed out. Make sure you have `[Debug]` selected in the 'Launch Type/Mode' otherwise 'Preferred Launcher' will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that only with adding the standard parameters to your 'main()' function is enough (I noticed that you're not using parameters in your 'main()':

check this [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=163089)

> I also see this problem. The folks at LinuxQuestions.org helped me make some progress... http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?t=518283

It appears that gcc 4.1.0 (ie. that in SUSE 10.1, 32-bit) has an optimization where if you don't use argc and argv in the body of main() those symbols are not present in the binary (even with -g and without any special optimization turned on). The 64-bit compiler doesn't do this incidentally.

You get the "Cannot access memory at address 0x0" from the gdb *command line* if you simply "break main" and print argc in a program that doesn't use argc/argv (and was compiled with gcc 4.1.0). I note your example doesn't use argc/argv.

This is true for C or C++ compilation.

Eclipse is presumably confused by this error in some way when it hits the first break. I was also getting the inability to stop at further breakpoints *until* I added code to reference argc/argv, or re-declare main (in C++) as "int main(int, char *[])" so that Eclipse wasn't expecting those symbols.

There is still an error in the gdb output window (no symbol "new" in the current context?), but breakpoints can be set.

HTH,
-nick